# Phonegap external html file

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

i have a problem with this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script language="javascript">
            function callWeb(){
                document.getElementById("myIframe").src = "MY NEW URL PHP";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
        <button onclick="callWeb()">GO</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to execute the javascript method callWeb I receive the error:

"Refused to display 'MY NEW URL PHP' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'."

I tried to execute it in web first but I'm interested just to let it works in phonegap.

Thanks in advance.
Regards